# How can I remove last 2 lines from a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I know you can remove blank lines with rstrip, but what about lines containg text?

For example my string output is:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC 
DDDD
FFFF
```

I want to remove DDDD & FFFF, so the output can be

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: scan=scan[:scan.rfind('\n')], however that just removes the very last line

scan= scan.split('\n',2)[2], this removes the first 2 lines :\ @Kajal

Comment: @A.L And what is the problem with that solution?

Comment: Why can't you remove the very last line twice??

Comment: @MichaelButscher i just cant figure out how to get it to remove the last 2 lines

Comment: find the second last index of "\n" and do substring

Comment: @cricket_007 i was trying to find something more efficient :/

Comment: Sure :) Just saying it's an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.rsplit` method is the correct tool when operating from the end (i.e. the right side of the string). Assuming the last line is newline terminated, 3 splits are necessary. We can tell the (r)split not to do more, so no `join` is needed to put the split pieces together.

```
string = """\
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
FFFF
"""
print(string.rsplit("\n",3)[0])
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of correct answers, here is a list based approach:

```
my_str = """AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
FFFF"""
print("\n".join(my_str.split("\n")[:-2]))
```

Result is

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

EDIT: `str` is indeed a reserved world, you should use some other variable.

Comment: To my knowledge str is a reserved word. isn't it? Anyways +1

Comment: @VisweswaranNagasivam You are absolutely right, i edited the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I made a working method that simply makes use of the string split and join methods to turn the string into an array of lines and then slice all but the last two lines.

```
string = "AAAA\nBBBB\nCCCC\nDDDD\nFFFF"

string = "\n".join(string.split("\n")[0:-2])
```

Alternatively, you can use rsplit to make two "splits" (into 3 pieces) and grab just the first piece.

```
string = string.rsplit("\n", 2)[0]
```